# Is periodic function over the entire $\mathbf{R}$ necessarily boundary

Tags: analysis

I think by intuition that the periodic function over the entire real line must be boundary. But I do not know how to prove it. If the function is continuous, the I can just choose a closed intervel of a period and it has obviously boundary. But when the function is not that great I have no idea in how to prove it. Or if that is not true, could you give an counterexample?

Comment: Take $f(x) = \mathrm{tan}(x)$ if $x$ is not in $\frac{\pi}{2} + \pi \mathbb{Z}$ and zero otherwise. Then $f$ is defined on $\mathbb{R}$ and periodic but it is not bounded.

Comment: The entire just means that the function has no undefined point.@Halbaroth

Comment: If you don't assume that the function is continuous, you can extend your function with undefined points by zero. I define $f$ such that $f(\frac{\pi}{2} + k\pi) = 0$ for any $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Thank you!@Halbaroth